# cannot load styles in angular cli new project

Tags: css, angular, google-chrome, angular-cli

I have just created a new project using angulari cli.

When I try to include styles.css file in index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

I receive this in Chrome's dev tools network tab:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Any idea on how to fix this? I am running locally using `ng serve`

[image]

I also try adding

```
./styles.css
/styles.css
styles.css
```

Comment: Have you tried *not* adding the link(s)? The css will be compiled and includes at run time.

Comment: Yes, actually you dont need to add them to your html. on your angular-cli.json you have place where you can add it. But styles that was created by CLI are added already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when we create angular-cli project styles.css will apply default which you can see in .angular-cli.json as

```
app: {
styles:[
  "styles.css"
]
```

}

here you can add more styles if you needed based on your project.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that it is loaded automatically through some server requests for js files. So it is loading the styles through javascript.

Answer (score 0):

For the new version angular cli, you no longer have to include the following lines

```css
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

in the index.html file. The cli will inject the contents automatically. So **remove** that line from the index.html and all should work.

if you need style.css just declare it in angular-cli.json as follows

```
 "styles": [
        "styles.scss",
      ],
```